# React unique key error on element that has key

Tags: reactjs, key, render

I'm rendering an modal named `attributemodal` in react.
The render method of `attributemodal` looks like this:

```
public render() {
    const name = this.props.activeTag.name;
    function findindex(element: any) {
      return element.name == name;
    }
    const index = this.props.possibleTags.findIndex(findindex);
    let attributes = [{name: "", helptexts: [{helptext: ""}] }];
    let infoText;
    if (index != -1) {
      attributes = this.props.possibleTags[index].attributes;
      infoText = this.props.possibleTags[index].helptexts[0].helptext;
    }
    const attr = attributes.map((item, key) =>
      <div style={{border: "1px solid black", padding: "10px"}} key={`attribute${key}`}>
        <b>{item.name}: </b>
       <input type="text" name={item.name} className="form-control" defaultValue={this.props.activeTag.attributes.length > 0 ? this.props.activeTag.attributes[key].value : ""} data-key={key} data-id={index}  onChange={this.onAttributeUpdate.bind(this)}/>
       <br/>
        <div className="info-box alert">
          <div className="msg" style={{padding: "0px 20px 0px 10px"}}>
            <i className="fa fa-info" style={{marginRight: "8px"}}></i> {item.helptexts[0].helptext}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
    return <Modal size="large" isOpen={this.props.isOpen}>
      <ModalHeader>{this.props.headerText + " " + this.props.activeTag.name}</ModalHeader>
      <ModalBody>
        <div className="info-box alert">
          <div className="msg" style={{padding: "0px 20px 0px 10px"}}>
            <i className="fa fa-info" style={{marginRight: "8px"}}></i> {infoText}
          </div>
        </div>
        {attr}
      </ModalBody>
      <ModalFooter>
        <Button onClick={this.props.startAction.bind(this)} className="btn-danger" disabled={this.state.isRunning}>{this.state.isRunning && <i className="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>} {this.props.addText}</Button>
      </ModalFooter>
    </Modal>;
  }
```

But it gives me this error:
[image]

As you can see I tried to add a `key` to the div inside my `map`.
But it still gives me this error!
It also says I'm rendering an `tr`, but I'm not

Can anyone explain why this is happening?

This is where I render my `attributemodal`:
This is inside the render method of my main application.

```
<AttributeModal
   key={"attributemodal"}
   startAction={this.onUpdateAttribute.bind(this)}
   isOpen={this.state.configTagModalActive}
   headerText={t("header")}
   activeTag={this.state.activeTag}
   addText={t("close")}
   possibleTags={this.state.possibleTags} 
/>
```

Comment: If you look at the traceback it's referring to a rendering of a `tr` and `AttributeModal`. Are you sure the error is in the code you posted here?

Comment: @keul yes the error is in there, I can give you also the code where I render the `attributemodal`

Comment: try using a key thats not the index of the item. for example item.name

Comment: theres a `>` behind `possibleTags`. not sure if thats a typo in your code or just in your question.

Comment: @vhflat I tried to do that, but still no change, also tried to render nothing but still gives me the error

Comment: why are you binding `this` at onchange and onclick?

Comment: Because my former programmer also does that, and it does not relate to my question, the onchange and onclick works